# Have Powershell process a list of objects from a C# program

Tags: powershell

I want to add a facility in a c# application where i can:

1) Take a collection of objects, and pass it to a powershell script from inside my c# application

2) Have the powershell script make changes to the the list of objects it was passed

3) Return that list of objects back to c#

I have an external class called Message

```
 public class Message 
    { 
        public String name { get; set; } 
        public String from { get; set; } 
        public String to { get; set; } 
        public String date { get; set; } 
        public String subject { get; set; } 
        public String body { get; set; } 
    }
```

I populate the PSDataCollection list class as such:

```
 PSDataCollection<Message> mlist = new PSDataCollection<Message>() 
          { 
              new Message {  to="user1", from="user2", date = "1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM EST", subject = "hi there" , body = "hi again" }, 
              new Message {  to="user1", from="user3", date = "1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM EST", subject = "new messages" , body = "new messages" } 
          }
```

In the powershell script we want it to 
1) Read each object 
2) Adjust the date field by adding 2 hours to it

Implementation issues:

The following code is our attempt at getting it working.  The first issue we hit was how to import the Message class from an external DLL.

We tried this:  Add-Type "G:\testBAL\bin\Debug\testBAL.dll" but  got errors

Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace TestProject 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
      static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            PSDataCollection<Message> mlist = new PSDataCollection<Message>() 
            { 
                new Message {  to="user1", from="user2", date = "1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM EST", subject = "hi there" , body = "hi again" }, 
                new Message {  to="user1", from="user3", date = "1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM EST", subject = "new messages" , body = "new messages" } 
            }; 
            mlist.Complete(); 

            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create() 
                .AddScript("Add-Type G:\testBAL\bin\Debug\testBAL.dll") 
                .AddCommand("Select-Object"); 

            IAsyncResult async = ps.BeginInvoke<Message>(mlist); 

            foreach(PSObject result in ps.EndInvoke(async)) 
            { 
                String to = ((Message)(result.BaseObject)).to; 
                Console.WriteLine("to=" + to); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a PowerShell Runspace to Set and Get variables in a PowerShell Session created in a .NET application. I edited your date parameter and removed the EST so it could be easily be parsed by PowerShell's Get-Date cmdlet.

HTH

Doug

```
var mlist = new PSDataCollection<Message>() 
{ 
    new Message {  to="user1", from="user2", date = "1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM", subject = "hi there" , body = "hi again" }, 
    new Message {  to="user1", from="user3", date = "1/10/2010 12:00:00 AM", subject = "new messages" , body = "new messages" } 
};

var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();
rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("list", mlist);
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = rs;

ps.AddScript(@"
    $list | ForEach {
        $_.date = (Get-Date($_.date)).AddHours(2)
    }   
");

ps.Invoke();

var result = rs.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("list") as PSDataCollection<Message>;
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.date);
}
rs.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description it appears  you are missing the -Path switch.

You have to specify the -Path when you pass a DLL directly.   See reference documentation here ... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315241.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've loaded a C# assembly into a PowerShell script and used it like this:

```
$dllPath = "C:\path\library.dll"
$tmp = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dllPath)
$obj = new-object Namespace.LibraryClass()
```